# Build error when attempting to build FBSDK Flutter ios

Tags: facebook, dart, flutter

Trying to setup facebook SDK on for flutter iOS but keep getting this error.

The SDK works for Andorid

Tried to clean the code and reinstall

```
/Users/abdi/Documents/project-philotes/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/FBSDKLoginCompletion.m:223:49: error: property 'isActive' not found on object of type 'FBSDKApplicationDelegate *'
  if ([FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance].isActive) {
                                                ^
/Users/abdi/Documents/project-philotes/ios/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/Internal/FBSDKLoginCompletion.m:272:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FBSDKSystemAccountStoreAdapter'
        [FBSDKSystemAccountStoreAdapter sharedInstance].forceBlockingRenew = YES;
```

Expected the app to build for the simulator

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, it's related with the Facebook pod version. Try using my fork, edit your `pubspec.yaml` file and add this dependency:

```
      flutter_facebook_login:
        git: https://github.com/diegoveloper/flutter_facebook_login.git
```

Comment: I was able to fix this with your repo. But is there a more permanent solution?

Comment: @SunojVijayan there will be once this PR is merged https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/pull/107 you can go back to using original `flutter_facebook_login` repo